# Is there a standard meaning for _csuid/__qsa in cookies?

Tags: security, browser, cookies

I was perusing my cookies, and discovered several cookies from various different sites, which all have the same value. They are all named "_csuid". I have another set, all from different sites, all with the same value, named "__qsa". It seemed rather strange that they would all be identical, despite coming from different sites.

In case it's relevant, I'm browsing with Camino on Leopard.

Does anyone know what these cookies are recording, since they appear to be tracking me across domains...?

Comment: Do you mean `__qca`? I can't find anything about `__qsa`.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that `_csuid` is from [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/), and `__qca` and `__qcb` from [Quantcast](http://www.quantcast.com/). Also, to my knowledge, the `__utm`* cookies are from [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/).

[Here](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsCookies.html)'s some good information on the Google Analytics cookies. It appears AddThis and Quantcast haven't published anything like that.